# Css layout bootstrap overlay

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, view

I know there is a similar question but I have tried them all and failed.
In this example, there are 4 rows with an image and a link in each.

I want each link to overlay each image but it always seems to take the whole width as the relative.

IE the link in the `"Mann"` is actually for the `"Badetuch"`.

I just want to set the css so the test class for each is in the horizontal centre for each image.

Setting them separately is just not ideal and for col-2 .test, I set it to 30% which should be 50% but absolute based on the image in col2.

I am using the views module from bootstrap to create the site.

Hope this makes sense.Any help will be appreciated.
Ta
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you do.

```css
.view-content > .row > div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="region region-content">
  <section id="block-system-main" class="block block-system clearfix">
    <div class="view view-produkte view-id-produkte view-display-id-page view-dom-id-WhyDidYouDoThisClassMakeThatNumberAnIDInstead">
      <div class="view-content">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <img src="https://bytesizemoments.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/placeholder.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            <a href="#" class="overlay">Link 1</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <img src="https://bytesizemoments.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/placeholder.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            <a href="#" class="overlay">Link 2</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <img src="https://bytesizemoments.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/placeholder.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            <a href="#" class="overlay">Link 3</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <img src="https://bytesizemoments.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/placeholder.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            <a href="#" class="overlay">Link 4</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

First of all, you make a "3-column" by writing "col-xs-3" (the setting for xs screen size is passed on to larger sizes unless otherwise indicated).
I set the parent div's margin and padding to 0 because you didn't have any space between your boxes in the example. I also gave them a border to differentiate the different images and a box-sizing of border-box so that they would fit in their columns properly.

So, to get the link to center horizontally within the div (and that's the key - it's within the same column div as the image), I set the width to 100%, which is 100% of the parent (the "col-xs-3") and then gave it a text-align of center. Anchor tags are inline elements by default; they only are as wide as the contained text requires them to be, so setting text-align: center without setting the width: 100% does nothing because you are essentially centering the text in the width that it occupies, so there is no visible effect. Setting width: 100% makes it take up the full width of the parent div, which gives it space to center in.

Now, to get it to center vertically on top of the image, I gave it position: absolute. This prevents it from moving out of the way of the image. An element with position: absolute does whatever it's told to do, relative to the first parent it encounters with a non-static value for position. (Which is why I set the parent div's content to relative but didn't give it a top or left value to move it.) After I set it to position: absolute, I have to tell it where to go relative to that parent, and I want it to go to the middle. The image is the largest element that parent contains, so the parent's height and width are equal to those of the image. I set the anchor tag's top value to 50%, which tells it to move down 50% of the height of the parent. But this is using the top-left corner of the anchor tag as the point to move, so consequently the link is not quite vertically centered - it's a little low. That's why I set margin-top to -1em. 1em = default font size. So -1em for margin-top tells it to move in the "negative top" direction - aka up - by a unit equal to the font-size. Now, the baseline is vertically centered relative to the parent element.